# JVM created via JNI in C doesn't work

Tags: java, c, jvm, java-native-interface

I'm quite new to JNI and right now I'm using this simple C program to create a JVM and call the main() from my Java project:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEnv* create_vm() {
    JavaVM* jvm;
    JNIEnv* env;
    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    args.nOptions = 1;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=CLASSPATH"; //This isn't the actual classhpath, but you get the idea
    args.options = options;
    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);
    if (ret<0){
        printf("\nUnable to Launch JVM");
    } else {
        printf("\nJVM launched successfully");
    }
    return env;
}

void invoke_class(JNIEnv* env) {
    jclass UncaughtExceptionClass;
    jmethodID mainMethod;
    jobjectArray applicationArgs;
    jstring applicationArg0;

    UncaughtExceptionClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "exceptioncatcher/ExceptionCatcher");

    mainMethod = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, UncaughtExceptionClass, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    applicationArgs = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 1, (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String"), NULL);
    applicationArg0 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "From C");
    (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, applicationArgs, 0, applicationArg0);

    (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, UncaughtExceptionClass, mainMethod, applicationArgs);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    JNIEnv* env = create_vm();
    invoke_class( env );
}
```

This works well when running a HelloWorld type java code, but my code actually sets a Default Uncaught Exception Handler. This handler will send the info collected for each uncaught exception to a thread that will process them and send them by email.

Right now these are pretty much all the classes created and it, obviously, won't catch a lot of uncaught exceptions right now. But I use the main() to try it out:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefaultExceptionHandler());
    Integer i = null;
    i++;
}
```

It works fine when I simply run it from netbeans, but the only thing that appears when using the C app is "JVM launched successfully".

Can anyone help on this one?

Comment: Could it be that your application exits before the error reporting thread is able to send the email? What's the reason for using a separate thread for this?

Comment: Why? Your simple program doesn't do anything that `java.exe` doesn't already do, and it misses out on a lot of other things that `java.exe` also does. What's the objective here?

Comment: Checking the return values of all JNI calls in invoke_class might reveal something.

Comment: As a matter of fact, i'm not entirely sure myself why they asked me to do it this way, being only an intern I don't really have my say in it. But fact is I found a way to make it work, just had to build the project and change my classpath to the .jar built.

Comment: BTW, what is your goal? IMO, messing with JNI is not the best option available in most cases.

Comment: You could accomplish the same goal by just making a copy of java.exe with the required name.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work in the end (never closed the question before), simply had to build the project and change the classpath to the .jar generated.